# Ternary notation equivalent of If Else statement in c#

Tags: c#

In order to shorten code, I am looking to substitute the below mentioned If Else statement to ternary notation but my code shows error.

```
if (txtMayAmt.Enabled)
{
    txtMayAmt.Text = txtAprilAmt.Text;
}
else
{
    txtMayAmt.Text = "0";
}
```

my ternary notation which is showing error is

```
((txtMayAmt.Enabled) ? (txtMayAmt.Text = txtAprilAmt.Text) : (txtMayAmt.Text = "0"));
```

Please advice with code.

Comment: What's the error? You want `txtMayAmt.Text = txtMayAmt.Enabled ? txtAprilAmt.Text : "0";`

Comment: syntax should look like `x = bool_test ? true_result : false_result`

Comment: Sorry for late response.My Internet was down.I would like to thank everybody for pointing me in the right direction.Now i can understand what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtMayAmt.Text = txtMayAmt.Enabled ? txtAprilAmt.Text : "0";
```

Answer (score 4):

The [ternary operator `?:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) uses the following pattern :

```
Variable = (Condition) ? (Value If True) : (Value If False)
```

So in your case, you would use the following equivalent statement :

```
// This will set the Text property to match April if enabled, otherwise "0"
txtMayAmt.Text = txtMayAmt.Enabled ? txtAprilAmt.Text : "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
txtMayAmt.Text = txtMayAmt.Enabled ? txtAprilAmt.Text : "0";
```